# Next.js 500 Internal Server Error right after calling useEffect Hook inside 404 Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am calling the useEffect hook to call a setTimeout function inside it so as to redirect the user back to the home page after 3 seconds using useRouter hook from Next.js and calling the push method on it. The page works fine when i dont call the useEffect hook inside the stateless functional component for 404 page and redirects me to the custom 404 page. But, then i get 500 internal server error every time i call useEffect Hook.

Error

> Terminal :next_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default(...) is not
> a function
> at PageNotFound (webpack-internal:///./pages/404.js:23:68)
> at processChild

```
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import useEffect from "react";
import useRouter from "next/router";


const PageNotFound = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      router.push("/");
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box className="page-not-found">
      <h1>Ooops..</h1>
      <h2>That page cannot be found</h2>
      <p>
        Go back to the
        <Link href="/">
          <a className={styles.notFoundHomePageLink}>Homepage.</a>
        </Link>
      </p>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default PageNotFound;
```

`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you imported `useRouter` the wrong way.
According to the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) it needs to be like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

Comment: was it the same error or something different?

Comment: I missed the curly braces on both useEffect and useRouter. Thanks a lot for pointing it out!!